# calculating requirements and dependencies hang

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When I try to update Eclipse ADT to the latest version of 22.3.0,

Menu->Help->Install New Software

Work with: adt-http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ (Always can't connect to https)

Then when I clicked Next, it had always shown "calculating requirements and dependencies" and had made no progress.

I have searched the solution which is to uncheck [Contact all updates sites during install to find required software].

So let more people who stuck in this question knowing the solution.

Comment: Thank Johnson for editing suggestions